# create a list, add an element and return it to the caller in one statement

Tags: java, list

Is there a way to create a list and add an element and return the resulting list in one statement ?

```
return new ArrayList<Email>().add(email);
```

Above does not work for obvious reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Are external libraries such as Guava an option for you?

Comment: While it's pretty easy to do in one line, why is that even a requirement? It also depends on what you actually need to do with the resulting list, as the obvious solution won't be modifiable.

Comment: You could create a method that takes an object as parameter and creates a new arraylist adding the object and returning the new arraylist.

Comment: I have an interface that returns a list of objects on a method. Some of the implementor just return one element. I don't want to code three lines just to return one element and also curious to see how it could have been done. In my prior life, I was a C developer :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Fixed-size solution

Try:

```
return Arrays.asList(email);
```

Note that the returned list will be fixed size. Quoting from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-):

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array. This method acts as bridge between array-based and collection-based APIs, in combination with [`Collection.toArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray--). The returned list is serializable and implements [`RandomAccess`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html).

So you can change elements in the returned `List`, but you cannot perform operations which change its size.

See this example:

```
String email = "as@as.com";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(email);

list.set(0, "bs@bs.com"); // OK
list.clear();             // throws UnsupportedOperationException
list.add("cc@cc.com");    // throws UnsupportedOperationException
```

### General solution

If you need to make the returned list completely modifiable, you can still do it in one line:

```
return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(email));
```

So basically just create a new [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) initialized with the fixed-size list created by `Arrays.asList()`. Although this isn't really idiomatic to how a `List` with one element should be created, it solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

This returns an immutable list containing the elements provided as arguments:

```
return List.of(elements);
```